# get a particular line from history, bash

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

How would I get like line 78 from history in Bash?

Like I know that I could do something along the lines of:

```bash
history | grep 78 | \
awk '{idex=2; while (idex <= NF) { printf $idex " "; idex++} print }' | \
sed '2!d; s/\s\s[0-9]*.*$//'
```

The text that I'm trying to get out of this is:

```
npm uninstall foo; npm install -g foo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `p` modifier will print any history expansion instead of executing it.

```
!78:p
```

Answer (score 1):

```
history | sed -n "`78 {s/^ *[0-9]\{1,\}[[:space:]]*\([^ ]\)/\1/p;q;}"
```

if you absolutely want sed and use of history command (for example to add a "#" at the start of the line to secure any action of string) or in ksh where `!78:p` does not work

Answer (score 0):

To get line 78 from history in bash, run the following:

```bash
!78
```

Comment: You will get it... and execute it!! So be careful

Comment: @fedorqui that's the idea :P  (I can think of any other reason why I would want to get a line from history...)  Oh, I see what you're saying.  You're saying that I better make sure that it's the line I want before just typing in `!<LINE>` willy-nilly.

Comment: Imagine you have done `rm -rf *` in `/tmp/mytest` and then you run this while being in `/`. I imagine it will produce a huge facepalm :D

Comment: @fedorqui do you know of any ways of verifying that line X is what I want without executing line X?  I mean, the only thing I can think of is to grep for the command like `history | grep npm`

Comment: Yes, you can also do `history | awk '$1==number'`. It will show the command. And if you are pretty sure it is what you want, then do `!number`. By the way, do you know you can also do `!!` to execute the previous command?

Comment: @fedorqui Oh, yeah, I'm well aware of `!!`, and I use it all the time, but a lot of the time the previous command is not the command that I want.

Comment: @chepner - `!78:p` should be an answer.  Can you assign the expansion to a variable?